# Barbarism , what's the great difference in slaughtering lakhs of animals in factories vs yajurvedic pashubandha?

Tags: vedas, puranas, dharma-shastras, vivekananda, non-vegetarian

In communicating Ramakrishna and Hinduism to the west, Vivekananda was cornered into possibly saying animal sacrifice is barbaric? Hunters, Mansaharis, Muslims, Christians, Buddhists and Hindus all eat meat. Is there a scriptural defence of this? I am a student of history and philosophy- for those willing to sell their souls for meat, it is quite justified, not barbaric at all

Comment: A principal emotion associated with people who kill is a bit of fear, their imagined hard heartedness, threat as a wielder of the butchers knife or chopper. We mentally place ourselves as the victim, and it is prudent to have that feeling.

Comment: How can one legitimately compare animal slaughter to offering animals to the deva-s to attain svarga?

Comment: As somebody who is associated with the Ramakrishna Mission, I assure you that Swami Vivekananda never branded meat-consumption as barbaric. It is only Arya Samaj & some people from North India (who in Swami Vivekananda's words, voluntarily feed ants with sugar in the name of compassion but don't hesitate to murder their own brother due to property dispute), that look down upon non-vegetarianism.